# Unable to locate name/value separator

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to run this command to put two items in a chest (I want to put four items in a chest, but I'm trying two first):

```
/blockdata -332 56 869 {Items:[1:{id:347,Count:1,Slot:12,tag:{display:{Name:"Time > Limit"}}}],[2:{id:399,Count:1,Slot:10,tag:{display:{Name:"Smash > Crystal"}}}]}
```

And It keeps saying "Unable to locate name/value separator"

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of problems with your command, but before we get to the problems, let's see the solution:

```
/blockdata -332 56 869 {Items:[{id:minecraft:clock,Count:1,Slot:12,tag:{display:{Name:"Time > Limit"}}},{id:minecraft:nether_star,Count:1,Slot:10,tag:{display:{Name:"Smash > Crystal"}}}]}
```

First thing to notice is that I'm using the item names instead of the ID numbers.  *This is required in 1.9*, and works in 1.8, so it's what you should use.  The second thing to notice is that I'm not numbering the list items, since it isn't really necessary.  Instead of potentially screwing it up, just leave them out.  The third thing, and what was really causing your problems, was that you were closing the list after the first item.  Notice that you have `],[` between your two items.  You need to just have the comma instead.